# How to throw a exception that doesnt inherit from Exception?

Tags: .net, exception

I would like to test some exception handling logic in the empty catch block of the below code.

```
try
{
    //Do Some stuff that throws a exception 
    //This is the code i need
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //Handle things that inherits from Exception
}
catch
{
    //Handle things that dont inherits from Exception
    //Want to test this code
}
```

Comment: A very important note that's missing is that the `doesnt inherit from Exception` is possible, but only at CLR1.0 platform, or with [WrapNonExceptionThrows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimecompatibilityattribute.wrapnonexceptionthrows.aspx) turned off - both of which are very rarely seen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting with CLR 2.0 this is not a scenario that you need to worry about.  The CLR will now automatically wrap all exceptions which do not derive from System.Exception with a new Exception of type `RuntimeWrappedException` ([Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimewrappedexception.aspx)).

This wrapping can be disabled by enabling a level of application compatibility but it is certainly not the normal or common case

Answer (score 5):

You cannot write code that throws a non-Exception in C#.  You would need to write it in IL (and compile using ILASM) or C++/CLI.

But, to be honest, I wouldn't worry about this scenario.  The ability to throw non-Exceptions is not used in the framework, and I doubt it is used in much third-party code.  I would only address this if you are using a library which you *know* throws non-Exceptions.