# What is the difference between the 3 catch block variants in C# ( 'Catch', 'Catch (Exception)', and 'Catch(Exception e)' )?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception, try-catch

In C#, what is the difference Between 'Catch', 'Catch (Exception)', and 'Catch(Exception e)' ?

The [MSDN article on try-catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0yd65esw.aspx) uses 2 of them in its examples, but doesn't explain the difference in usage purposes.

```
try
{}
catch 
{}

try 
{}
catch (Exception)
{}

try
{}
catch(Exception e)
{}
```

How do these differ?  Which ones catch all exceptions, and which ones catch specific exceptions?

Comment: all 3 catch all exceptions, the difference is the third you can retrieve a message

Comment: The documentation on MSDN is pretty helpful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Comment: You should never catch System.Exception.  Here is a decent article. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7557/Exception-Handling-in-C-with-the-quot-Do-Not-Catch

Comment: And the second can specify a type.

Comment: -1 for Poor research. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805987/catch-vs-catch-exception-e-and-throw-vs-throw-e and possibly a million others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch and Catch(Exception e) in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336951/catch-and-catchexception-e-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Closed as "not a real question"?  A duplicate, perhaps, but it is certainly a valid question.  Be sure you're sending the right message to new users when you decide to play God.

Comment: How is this not a real question? would asking the difference between a duck, dog, and fish not be a question either?  If you read this, please vote to re-open the question, as it is more in depth than others of the same level on this topic.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In short...

`Catch` without a parameter will receive any exception but provide no means to address it.

`Catch (Exception)` will essentially do the same thing, because you've specified the root `Exception` type.  As opposed to `Catch (IOException)` which would only catch the `IOException` type.

`Catch (Exception ex)` catches all exceptions and provides a means to address it via the `ex` variable.

Read more:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

Answer (score 46):

No one has yet mentioned the historical aspect of this question.

In .NET it is legal to throw an object that does not derive from `Exception`. (It is not legal in C#, but it is in some other managed languages.) Many people are unaware of this fact, but it is legal. Since that is *crazy*, in .NET 2.0 the default was changed: if you attempt to throw something that is not an exception then it is automatically wrapped in the `RuntimeWrappedException` class which obviously *is* an exception.  That object is then thrown.

Because of this oddity, in C# 1.0 it was common to see code that did both:

```
try
{ do something }
catch(Exception) 
{ handle the exception }
catch
{ handle the thrown non-exception }
```

And in fact there were security and correctness issues; there are situations in which for security reasons you *must* catch anything that is thrown (possibly to re-throw it) and people would think reasonably that `catch(Exception)` caught everything, but it didn't.

Fortunately since .NET 2.0 things have been more sensible; you can rely on `catch {}`, `catch(Exception) {}` and `catch(Exception ex) {}` to all catch everything should you need to.

And finally: if for some crazy reason you want to turn on the C# 1.0 behavior, you can put

```
[assembly:System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = false)]
```

in your program.

Comment: +1 because you barely have any reputation.  Oh, and the history lesson :)

Comment: Related thread: [How to throw a exception that doesnt inherit from Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622755/how-to-throw-a-exception-that-doesnt-inherit-from-exception)

Comment: Is this true also for .NET Compact Framework since version 2.0?

Comment: @Thomas: This is a question-and-answer site. If you have a question, *post it as a question* and someone will answer it. I note that "does framework X support feature Y?" is a question that can be answered by you by trying it.

Answer (score 9):

First version catches all exceptions deriving from the Exception class.

The second version catches specified exception.

The third version catches a specified exception with a declared name. Then in the catch block you can use this object, for example, to see the complete error: `e.ToString();`

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Actually, you would use `e.Message`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: no, you should not use e.Message. That's only the "pretty" message for the user. e.ToString() displays all the information, including inner exceptions.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Do you refer to the "stack trace"?  If so, then I would agree.

Comment: Also note that the versions catch `Exception` types or anything *deriving* from `Exception`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: not just e.StackTrace. ToString will display inner exceptions, server-side exceptions, etc.

Answer (score 6):

All of them do basically the same thing, the difference being the amount of information they provide about the error.

`catch (foo ex) {}` will filter out all exceptions, except those that can be cast to type `foo`. It also gives you the instance of the error for you to work on.

`catch (foo) {}` does the same as above, but it doesn't give you the instance of the exception. You'll know the type of the exception, but won't be able to read information from it.

Notice that in both of those cases, if the type of the exception is `Exception`, they'll catch all exceptions.

`catch {}` catches all exceptions. You don't know the type it caught and you can't access the instance.

You can choose which one to use based on how much information you need from the exception should it be caught.

Regardless of which one you use, you can pass the caught exception forward by using the command `throw;` (without arguments).

Answer (score 3):

In your example, nothing, since you're not doing anything with the exception. But to clarify…

- This catches everything but does nothing with the exception.

  ```
  catch {}
  ```

  This is only useful when you want to say guarantee a return from a method.
- This catches only exceptions of type `Exception` (which is everything) but does nothing with the exception.

  ```
  catch (Exception) {}
  ```

  This is useful if you wanted to limit the type of exception being caught by specifying which types you want to handle. Any other exceptions will bubble up the call stack until a proper handler is found.
- This catches only exceptions of type `Exception` (which is everything) and could do something with the exception, but happens to do nothing

  ```
  catch (Exception ex) {}
  ```

  This technique gives you a lot more options. You could log the exception, inspect the `InnerException`, etc. And again you can specify which types of exceptions you wish to handle.

Unless you're re-throwing the exception somehow, all of these are bad practice. In general, you should only catch the exceptions you can meaningfully handle and allow anything else to bubble up.

Comment: The language does not allow a `catch` block to come after another `catch` block which already handles every type that this `catch` would handle. But it does allow `catch (Exception) { ... } catch { ... }` where supposedly that last block is unreachable. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12615845/1336654), some languages other than C# might "throw" an object that is not a `System.Exception`. Is it true? I have heard that in that case the exotic object will be wrapped in an `Exception` by the runtime after all, but is that correct?

Comment: Lippert just explained this in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding catch(Exception e) will give you access to the Exception object, which contains details about the exception that was thrown, such as its Message and StackTrace; it is useful to log this information to help diagnose bugs. A simple catch without declaring the exception that you're trying to catch won't give you access to the exception object.

Also, catching the base Exception is generally considered bad practice because it's far too generic, and where possible you should always case for a specific exception first. For example, if you're working with files you might consider the following try/catch block:

```
try{
    //open your file and read/write from it here
}catch(FileNotFoundException fe){
    //log the message
    Log(fe.Message);
}catch(Exception e){
    //you can catch a general exception at the end if you must
}finally{
    //close your file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the highest level they are all the same; they all catch exceptions.

But to drill down further, in the first case you are catching an exception and doing nothing with it (you don't have a defined type).  In the second example, you are catching an exception of the Exception type.  In your last example, you are catching the same Exception type as in example 2 but, now you are putting the exception into a variable that would allow you to show it in a MessageBox or:

```
e.Message
```

It's important to note as well that exceptions are tiered meaning, if you are catching multiple types of exceptions in the same try/catch block, you go from the most specific exception type to the most general.  Like this:

```
try {
}
catch (SqlException sqlExc) {
}
catch (Exception exc) {
}
```