# How to return the inner exception when a selenium timeout occurs?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, expected-condition

I currently have a solution using Selenium WebDriver and .NET Framework, using the following code to create waits for interacting with web elements as part of our automation solution.

`wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));`

This works well for waiting for an element to load in the screen, but it does not contain the most useful of message, for example if an element is not clickable the following is returned:

`Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 60 seconds`

Rather than the NoSuchElement exception which identifies what record is looking to be entered.

This becomes even more of an issue when trying to validate a record value e.g. 
`wait.Until(webdriver => element.GetAttribute("value") == expectedValue);`

As this returns the timeout issue, rather than actually declaring what the difference is, which for example a Nunit Assert will give you, here I am working around this with the following

```
try
{
customWait.Until(webdriver => element.GetAttribute("value") == expectedValue);
}
catch
{
// to display assertion error when unable to validate attribute in given time
Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, element.GetAttribute("value"));
}
```

Is there a better way which can override the default timeout response with the original message of the internal error, e.g. after x seconds of trying to find an element return a NoSuchElement exception for the element searching for,  rather than a TimeoutException.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer exactly. I suggest that you find which exception is thrown and change your catch clause to `catch(SomeException e)` and look at its attributes. It probably has a cause.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `Assert.Fail()` with your own custom message.

Comment: WebDriverWait will ignore those exceptions, though they are still thrown.  You could get those, but they would be happening every 1/2 second I think... until it's found.   If you hit the timeout the ExpectedCondition is false, so choose the condition you are looking for: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html   (The exception to this would be StaleElement, which does not necessarily mean the condition has not been met... )

Comment: Sounds like you just need to learn more about exception handling: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17073834/3092298